# What is the weekly average of coronal mass ejections the sun sends out?

Tags: sun

What is the average number of coronal mass ejections that the sun sends out each week, including those that are not directed towards Earth?

Answer (score 4):

From [the CME Chase Page at NASA (http://pwg.gsfc.nasa.gov/istp/nicky/cme-chase.html)](http://pwg.gsfc.nasa.gov/istp/nicky/cme-chase.html) :

> Near solar activity maximum, the sun produces about 3 CMEs every day,
>   whereas near solar minimum it produces only about 1 CME every 5 days.

That page also has a lot of interesting information about CME's, their mass, speed and their magnetic field. Well worth a read.